# Lógica para validar horários livres em agenda

Tags: php, sql, data, datetime

Preciso validar um intervalo entre datas, que funciona assim:

[image: Esquema cenário atual e o desejado]

Ou seja, se já possui um agendamento das 13:00 às 14:00, os demais agendamentos só serão possíveis se for antes das 13:00 e depois das 14:00.

Tentei a seguinte query, mas falha quando a data de início é menor e data final maior que a que está no banco:

```sql
SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE livro_idlivro = 4 AND
((UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-11-15 11:59:00') >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(data_entrada) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-11-15 11:59:00') < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(data_saida)))
 OR ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-11-15 17:59:00') >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(data_entrada) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-11-15 17:59:00') < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(data_saida)))
 AND livro_idlivro =4
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

O problema é organizar a lógica (que é simples).

Basicamente para um horário não coincidir com outro, você precisa de apenas testar duas condições.

Dividi em duas possibilidades, mas note que a lógica é análoga em ambas (é só uma inversão da expressão):

### Teste de "Horário não coincidente" ou "agenda livre"

Se quiser obter Horário não coincidente, são só essas duas:

- Data de início do evento A maior (ou igual) que o fim do evento B

**OU**

- Data de final do evento A menor (ou igual) que o começo do evento B

Que em PHP é:

```
$livre = $inicioA => $finalB || $finalA <= $inicioB
```

### Teste de "Horário coincidente" ou "Agenda ocupada"

Se quiser Horário coincidente, só use estas outras duas:

- Data de início do evento A menor (ou igual) que o fim do evento B

**E**

- Data de final do evento A maior (ou igual) que o fim do evento B

Que em PHP é:

```
$ocupado = $inicioA < $finalB && $finalA > $inicioB
```

Em ambos os casos, você pode intercambiar os `>=` e `<=`por `>` e `<` caso um evento terminado exatamente 9h00 não possa "conviver" com um evento iniciado 9h00 em algum cenário mais específico.

### Em SQL

Exemplo de *query* para achar livres, mas com "convivência" na hora da "virada":

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE
   ( data1_inicio >= data2_fim OR data1_fim <= data2_inicio )
   AND id_livro = 4
;
```

Notar os `( )` na parte que testa as datas. Fica ainda a sugestão de trabalhar com datas nativas no DB, em vez de converter dinamicamente em segundos.

### Analisando visualmente a lógica:

Tomando por base esses 6 eventos:

```
           AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
           |                 |
1 BBBBBBBBBBBB               |           Ocupado
2          |  BBBBBBBBBBBBBB |           Ocupado
3          |            BBBBBBBBBBBBB    Ocupado
4 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB Ocupado
5 BBBB     |                 |           Livre
6          |                 | BBBBBBBBB Livre
```

Temos essa tabela-verdade com todas as possíveis comparações:

```
1 A ini < B ini  A ini < B fim  A fim > B ini  A fim < B fim  Ocupado
2 A ini > B ini  A ini < B fim  A fim > B ini  A fim < B fim  Ocupado
3 A ini > B ini  A ini < B fim  A fim > B ini  A fim > B fim  Ocupado
4 A ini < B ini  A ini < B fim  A fim > B ini  A fim > B fim  Ocupado
5 A ini < B ini  A ini < B fim  A fim < B ini  A fim < B fim  Livre
6 A ini > B ini  A ini > B fim  A fim > B ini  A fim > B fim  Livre
  Condicao 1     Condicao 2     Condicao 3     Condicao 4
   (inutil)        (util)         (util)        (inutil)
```

- Perceba que as condições 1 e 4 não nos ajudam em nada;
- As condições 2 e 3 bastam para determinar o que é livre e o que é ocupado.

Answer (score 4):

Para verificar se um intervalo de datas está livre, você precisa verificar se o intervalo não coincide com os outros intervalos cadastrados.

Existe uma forma simples para verificar se existe uma interseção entre dois períodos de datas. O critério é o seguinte:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Tabela
 WHERE Data_Ini_Periodo1 <= Data_Fim_Periodo2 
   AND Data_Fim_Periodo1 >= Data_Ini_Periodo2
```

A condição será verdadeira sempre que houver uma sobreposição entre Periodo1 e Periodo2.

No exemplo abaixo, a condição será verdadeira para os registros 2 e 3:

```
Data_Ini_Periodo1 = 15/11/2017 11:00
Data_Fim_Periodo1 = 15/11/2017 13:59

   Data_Ini_Periodo2   Data_Fim_Periodo2  Resultado_Condicao_Intersecao
1  15/11/2017 09:00    15/11/2017 09:59   falso
2  15/11/2017 10:00    15/11/2017 11:59   verdadeiro
3  15/11/2017 12:00    15/11/2017 12:59   verdadeiro
4  15/11/2017 15:00    15/11/2017 15:59   falso
```

**Para verificar se um período está livre ou ocupado**, podemos construir a seguinte query:

```
select case when exists(select * 
                          from agenda
                         where @data_inicio <= data_saida
                           and @data_fim >= data_entrada)
            then 'Já existe agendamento para esse horário'
            else 'Período livre' end
```

**Para obter os períodos que coincidem** com um determinado período, podemos fazer:

```
select * 
  from agenda
 where @data_inicio <= data_saida
   and @data_fim >= data_entrada
```

**Para obter os períodos que não coincidem**, podemos fazer:

```
select * 
  from agenda
 where not(@data_inicio <= data_saida
           and @data_fim >= data_entrada)
```

Comment: Que linguagem é essa?

Comment: Olá big mister! muito obrigado pelas dicas, estarei implementando futuramente desta forma, como estou fazendo pra entregar para ontem, mais pra frente vou lapidando/otimizando as funcionalidades. Muito grato pela ajuda!!!! Qualquer coisa estou a disposição  :)

Comment: @dvd alterei a resposta para deixa-la mais simples. Acho que agora ficou mais fácil para identificar a linguagem.